# Where is Atom keeping its state?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm on OSX and had a file open in Atom which I hadn't given a name to. I had to restart my computer and when it came back again I clicked the wrong thing and it forgot all the old file names, and the unnamed file seems to be gone without a trace. If I use Time Machine to restore the .atom file to an old state it detects that something is 'wrong' and pulls the most recent state from some other location (it gets recent filenames from somewhere). Any idea where it's getting that state from?

Answer (score 10):

The literal answer to my question, found using some aggressive grepping, is `./Library/Application Support/Atom/IndexedDB/file__0.indexeddb.leveldb`.

It appears to be that the dialog which caused Atom to forget my file list was shown as the result of a real bug rather than bad intentional UX.

Here are the instructions which got my file contents back (courtesy someone in the Atom slack channel):

1. Open the Chrome Dev Tools in Atom using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
2. Click the *Application* tab
3. In the tree view on the left of this tab, expand *IndexedDB* > *AtomEnvironments* and click on the table `states`
4. In the grid on the right, you'll see one or more entries keyed with `editor-<some hash>`
5. For each of those entries, expand the Object in the Value column and then expand this tree: `Object` > `value` > `project` > `buffers`
6. For each file in the "buffers" list, expand it and try to find the untitled file, it won't have a `filePath` property.  The `text` field will have the file contents.